# Data Studio Community Connector Deployment, Share and Access Questions

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

After we build a Data Studio Community Connector, we would deploy it.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#12

And we will get a **deployment ID**.

My Questions are:

- The community connector we just created, would it be visible to the public? Or in other words, people can find out this newly deployed connector from search or connectors directory etc?
- If I want someone to use this new connector, do I have to share my apps script project (for this data studio connector) to them? Or they can access it if they have the deployment ID?
  -

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Share](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/share) guide on Data Studio Developer site talks about this in details.

1. If you create a new deployment, people **cannot** find out this newly deployed connector from search or connectors directory.
2. If you want someone to use this new connector, the user need to have read access to the script project in order to execute it. You do not have to make the script link available to them. See the [Share](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/share) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks. The function "publish --> deploy ..." and the term "community connector" makes me "worry" that it is already open to public.